# How to bind the Y value of a Polygon point

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-8

for a WP8 application I would like to bind the Y Value of a Polygon Point to a property. But it doesn't seem possible as I get the error message "XamlParseException" at the binding line

Here is the Xaml code :

```
       <Polygon Grid.Row="0" Fill="#66323232">
            <Polygon.Points>
                <Point X="0" Y="0"/>
                    <Point X="0" Y="{Binding HauteurPopUp}"/>
                    <Point X="1" Y="{Binding HauteurPopUp}"/>
                <Point X="1" Y="0"/>
                <Point X="0" Y="0"/>
            </Polygon.Points>
   </Polygon>
```

and here is the property

```
    public Int32 HauteurPopUp
    {
        get
        {
            return 300;
        }
    }
```

Any idea ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

`as I get the error message "XamlParseException"`

That's not a message, that's an exception *Type*.

The message would probably be that `Y` isn't a DependencyProperty so you can't bind to it.  This binding will never work.

Even if the binding were possible, once you update the value of Y, there is no *change notification* of this, so the `Polygon` won't know that any of its points have changed.

What you need to do is bind to `Polygon.Points`, which *is* a DependencyProperty of type [PointCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pointcollection.aspx).  Unfortunately, `PointCollection` doesn't implement any observable interfaces, so you can't just change one instance; every time one point changes, you have to create a new `PointCollection` and update the `Polygon`, either manually or by setting a property that is bound to `Polygon.Points`.

I won't do the code for you, but the algorithm goes like this

1. On load, create a `PointCollection`, fill it with the initial slate of `Point`s it should contain, and set `Polygon.Points` equal to this collection (directly or via a Binding)
2. Wait for a change to any individual `Point` in the collection (???)
3. <s>Profit</s> Create a new `PointCollection`, fill it with (you can reuse the same) `Points`, with updates applied where needed, and set `Polygon.Points` equal to this instance
4. Go to step 2.